# Correct way of passing and reading parameters to a .swf in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

What is the preferred way of passing parameters to a Flex application deployed as a `.swf` and how do I read the parameters from Flex?

I'm looking for the equivalent of passing and reading URL parameters in Flex land.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use FlashVars.

```
var paramObj:Object = Application.application.parameters;
trace(paramObj['foo']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getQuerystringProperty(property:String):String {
  var bm:IBrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();
  var oArgs:Object = {};
  bm.init("", "");
  oArgs = mx.utils.URLUtil.stringToObject(bm.fragment, “&”);
  if (oArgs[property])
    return oArgs[property].toString();
  return "";
}
```

Gets the QueryString from within Flex (no ExternalInterface).

Comment: Actually, BrowserManager does use ExternalInterface.

Answer (score 0):

embed the swf object in an html page and then use external interface.  These articles should help you:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/2/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

[Flex Examples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/04/11/getting-javascript-variables-into-your-flex-applications-using-the-externalinterface-api/)